# How to use sortProperties: ['lastName']

Tags: ember.js, ember-data

I'd like to sort an Array or users which gets fetched by ember-data. I can't figure out to sort the array be `lastName`. The following code doesn't do the job. How can I fix it?

**app.js**

```
App.UsersRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
  model: function() {
    return App.User.find();
  }
});

App.UsersController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  sortProperties: ['lastName'],
  sortAscending: true
})
```

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <table class='table table-striped'>
      {{#each model itemController="user"}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

Comment: does sorting work by leaving out the itemController and just render the model, only curiosity...

Comment: What happen if you don't define the `itemController`? It's not obvious to me why it doesn't work.

Comment: Try replacing `model` with `arrangedContent`

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kudos to [Bradley Priest](https://stackoverflow.com/users/365865/bradley-priest) for answering the question. Using `this` in the template does the trick.

**index.html**

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="users">
  <table class='table table-striped'>
      {{#each this itemController="user"}}
        <tr>
          <td>{{lastName}}</td>
        </tr>
      {{/each}}
  </table>
</script>
```

Comment: Can you see if `this` works instead of `arrangedContent`, technically Ember should use `arrangedContent` by default

Comment: By using `model` you were accessing the underlying object of the controller (the same as using `content`). By accessing it via `this` or `context` or even leaving it blank, you will get automatically delegated to `arrangedContent`