# Ember sortProperties explained

Tags: sorting, properties, ember.js

Can someone tell me why the person's list does not get reordered when using

sortProperties: ['name'], sortAscending: false

I am using ember-1.0.0-rc.6 and ember data store version 13 and the DS.FixtureAdapter

```
App.Person = DS.Model.extend({
name: DS.attr('string'),
trackNumber: DS.attr('number'),
})

App.Person.FIXTURES = [
{id: 1, name: 'aron face', trackNumber: 2},
{id: 2, name: 'bob sinclair', trackNumber: 1}
];

App.PersonsRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
model: function() {
return App.Person.find();
}
});

App.Router.map(function() {
this.resource('persons', function() {
this.resource('person', { path: ':person_id' });
});
});

App.ApplicationController = Ember.Controller.extend();

App.PersonsController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
sortProperties: ['name'],
sortAscending: false,

newPerson: function(){
    App.Person.createRecord({id: new Date().getTime(), name: 'Created person'});
},
remove: function () { .... }
});

App.personView = Em.View.extend({ ... });
```

Comment: Ok i am sorry for this post here is the answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16429067/how-to-use-sortproperties-lastname

Comment: you should remove your question or post an answer and accept it if you found a solution